# Leaflet Custom TileLayer for ArcGIS Cache Tiles in Folder

Tags: leaflet, esri-leaflet

This is ArcGIS Server tile cache folder structure on a server.

[image]

I need to get these tiles on my Leaflet map. I need to create a new TileLayer. I will extend existing TileLayer layer object's `getTileUrl()` method.

```
L.TileLayer.MyCustomLayer = L.TileLayer.extend({
    getTileUrl: function(coords){
        ?????
    }
});
```

I need to create new tile url address by `coords` parameter of `getTileUrl()` method.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I have a simple python script to rename the folders and files to standard naming and allow for a normal call from leaflet.

Answer (score 1):

if the tiled map service has been published to ArcGIS Server, i'd recommend using Esri Leaflet to load it via the service url.

you can find a live sample here:
http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/tile-layer-2.html

Comment: Map service has not been published. Using cache is fast than service.